# How to open component in new browser tab in angular from another component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I want to open a component in new browser tab from another compoent.

Here in my AppComponent html file has a button. when I click on this button I want to open
MapComponent.html file in new browser tab. Here after click on it map component is open in new browser tab. but button also showing in new tab. But I don't want to show any HTML file related to the other component in the MapComponent.html file. I want to show only MapComponent data in that tab. how to do it. Thanks.

**App-component.html**

```
<button (click)="openMapInNewTab()">Open Map</button>
```

**App-component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'routeApp';

  constructor(private router: Router) {}


  openMapInNewTab() {
    const url = '/map';
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }
}
```

**Map-component.html**

`<p>map works!</p>`

**Map-component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent {

}
```

**AppModule **

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MapComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`AppRoutingModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: MapComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Firstly in your routes you have declared MapComponent but you didn't give any path to it, try adding `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside your `app.component.html` so navigation between components will be available. Just FYI setting up your issue in any code editor online will help us understanding your issue better and finding solution to it easier

Comment: @gentbrika. in this senario after adding <router-outlet></router-outlet> app.component.html file button also show in the map.component.html file. I want to open only map.component.html file in another tab. should not show button or anything related to the map.component.html file.

Comment: Why aren't you using angular's method? `const url = this.router.serializeUrl(
    this.router.createUrlTree(['/map'])
  );

  window.open(url, '_blank');`

Comment: @gentbrika i used this also. but still button is move to map component. can you check this link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ykluml?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&title=Angular%20Starter

Comment: I cant see the content, it just shows loading...

Comment: @gentbrika can you check main.ts file. in my local application i have same code. but in here after copied that code showing loading. do you know the reason

Comment: @gentbrika ok I have fixed it. can you check it now

Comment: Yes it works now, let me check it

Comment: @gentbrika sure. waiting for your response.

Comment: Check the comments please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to it is firstly you need to add `<router-outlet>` tag so the application can navigate between components, after that i have separated the components so created a new component for button `button.component.ts`, declared it in routes also. This will solve the issue and here you can find [solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cuojqk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)

Comment: Thanks !! appreciate your help. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi. i have one question related to this. suppose instead open component in new browser tab. how to open it in new browser window.